# ftp: connect: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action

Tags: aix, ftp, telnet

cannot ftp through port 21

Get below error when trying to ftp

```
ftp: connect: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
```

Has any one came across above error and having any soultion please.

OS:  AIX 6

Comment: Do you need to be in IPSec tunnel in order to reach this server?

Comment: tagging onto lese's question, if you're using an IPsec tunnel, do you have IZ78607 (for AIX 6100-05) or IZ75664 (for AIX 6100-06) - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1IZ69898